# AngularJS injection error in a resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I'm trying to get user profile metadata into a resolve as a promise which is then used by another promise get information based on a value in the user profile.

```
myApp.config( function myAppConfig ( $routeProvider, authProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/wapmap', {
        templateUrl:  'wap_tools/wap_map.html',
        controller: 'wapMapClr',
        resolve: {
            mapres: function(profilePromise, service2) {
                profilePromise.then(function(profile) {
                    var viewerId = profile.app_metadata.viewers[1].viewerId;
                     return service2.getPromise(viewerId)
                })
                     .then(function(response2) {    
                       makelayerGroup(response2);
                       mapView(response2);
                       hasPhotos = response2.vwrSettings[0].photos;
                       return
                  })
            })
          }
        },
        requiresLogin: true
    });
```

This is the authProvider. It is also included in the config.

```
          authProvider.init({
          domain: 'someapp.eu.auth0.com',
          clientID: 'abcdsefghqwert12345',
          callbackURL: location.href,
          //URL when not logged in 
          loginUrl: '/Login' 

          });


      authProvider.on('loginSuccess', function($rootScope, $location, profilePromise, idToken, store, auth, userService) {
      console.log("Login Success");
      profilePromise.then(function(profile) {

          userService.setUser(auth.profile); 

          store.set('profile', profile);
          store.set('token', idToken);
          $location.path('/wapmap');
      });
      $rootScope.loggedIn = auth.isAuthenticated;
      $location.path('/wapmap');
      });
```

This throws the following error:

```
     [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: profilePromiseProvider <- profilePromise <- mapres
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=profilePromiseProvider%20%3C-%20profilePromise%20%3C-%20mapres
            at angular.js:68
            at angular.js:4511
            at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
            at angular.js:4516
            at getService (angular.js:4664)
            at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
            at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
            at angular-route.min.js:10
            at Object.forEach (angular.js:335)
            at angular-route.min.js:10
```

So this looks like an injection error - how do I get the profilePromise data into the resolve?

Comment: Don't use minified version of angular.js during development.

Comment: Try to inject profilePromise in to app config: .config(['$routeProvider', 'profilePromise', function($routeProvider, profilePromise){$routeProvider.when...

Comment: Make sure you inject profilePromise service

Comment: @Sibi Raj Thank you. I have changed to non-minified version of angular.js and updated the question with the non-minified error message.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've added where the promise is set (in 'authProvider') to the question. It's also defined in myApp.config.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: No still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155224/discussion-between-sibi-raj-and-robert).

Answer (score 2):

The [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=profilePromiseProvider%20%3C-%20profilePromise%20%3C-%20mapres) tells you:

> Unknown provider: profilePromiseProvider <- profilePromise <- mapres

Be sure that you defined properly `profilePromise` service/factory and it is loaded